# How to plot the trajectory of a particle using x y data from a txt file in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot the trajectory of a particle using x y data which is in a txt file using python. I keep getting the error message list index out of range in the y.append line. I've checked the txt file there doesn't seem to be any extra spaces or anything. How would I fix this to plot the trajectory?

```py
#import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X,Y=[],[]
for line in open('20130320_Track_17_5_rpm.txt','r'):
    values=[str(s) for s in line.split()]
    X.append(values[0])
    Y.append(values[1])
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you show a few lines from your data? Also, you could catch the exception and print out your data when it occurs - then it's easier to see how that data caused the exception.

Comment: Heres a few lines from my data

Comment: 0067 0100, 0064 0107, x and y values are separated by commas. data is displayed as column of x and column of y values

Comment: @Freya could you put this sample data from the comment to the question so that it would be convenient for others to test/fix it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Since, your data has the following structure,

```sh
0067 0100, 0064 0107,...
```

Here's the updated solution.

### Updated for your data:

```py
# write dummy data to file
x = np.arange(10)
y = x*2 + 3
data = ','.join([ str(a) + ' ' + str(b) for a, b in zip(x, y) ])
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)

# read data from file
fname = 'out.txt'
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    stream = f.read().replace(', ', ',').replace(' ', ',').split(',')
X, Y = [], []
for i in range(len(stream)//2):
    X.append(2*i)
    Y.append(2*i+1)
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

### If instead your data had multiple rows: two columns

Try this. Using `numpy.genfromtxt()`. Since, you did not mention what delimiter/separator is used, I assumed it to be *a single space* character in the following example.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fname = '20130320_Track_17_5_rpm.txt'
data = np.gentfromtxt(fname, delimiter=' ')
X, Y = data[:,0], data[:,1]
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

### Example with Dummy Data

```py
# Create and Write Dummy Data to file: 'out.txt'
x = np.arange(10)
y = x*2 + 3
data = '\n'.join([ str(a) + ' ' + str(b) for a, b in zip(x, y) ])
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)

np.genfromtxt('out.txt', delimiter=' ')
```

**Output**:

```sh
array([[ 0.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  5.],
       [ 2.,  7.],
       [ 3.,  9.],
       [ 4., 11.],
       [ 5., 13.],
       [ 6., 15.],
       [ 7., 17.],
       [ 8., 19.],
       [ 9., 21.]])
```

Comment: I've tried this code I get the error message too many indices for this array

Comment: @Freya Did you copy and paste the code and the dummy data? Or, did you just apply the code on your data?

Comment: I just applied the code to my data. I'm not sure if that's right?

Comment: No, that would not work directly. Your data is a single line, not like this example that I shared. Normally, data is kept in columns. But that's not the case for you. I am updating the solution. Please take a look at the top-most section once I update.

Comment: @Freya Try now. It should work. Use the section specifically meant for your data (at the top).

Comment: @Freya There was a correction `i --> 2*i` and `i+1 --> 2*i+1`. Please make sure you use the updated code.

Answer (score -1):

0067 0100, 0064 0107, x and y values are separated by commas. data is displayed as column of x and column of y values

with this statement - i undesrtand that
x= 0067 0100
y=0064 0107

I created a test file, test.txt

0067 0100, 0064 0107
0059 0596, 5668 8999
1224 5623, 5556 4566

X,Y=[],[]
for line in open('test.txt','r'):

```
values=[ str(s.replace(' ','').strip())  for s in line.split(',')]
X.append(values[0])
Y.append(values[1])
```

plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.show()
print(X,Y)

[image]

Comment: use comma in split function